# Sap server: Process not found error while trying to connect tizen emulator(2.3) and samsung galaxy note

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-emulator

I've to connect Tizen emulator with Samsung s4 or Samsung note. But I'm not able to connect anything. I've tried the following steps:

> 1. Uninstalled Samsung gear app
> 2. Installed the 3 apks given in the order    a) SAccessoryService_Emul.apk    b) SAFTCore_Emul.apk    c)
>      HostManagerForEmul.apk
> 3. Gave adb -d forward tcp:8230 tcp:8230 in the terminal and
> 4. Tried killall sap-server in sdb of emulator

Am I following the correct steps? Can someone help me out of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are following an old method.

Try this:

1. Download apks from this [link](http://img-developer.samsung.com/contents/cmm/gear/Applications_for_Emulator.zip)
2. After download extract the zip and copy them to the host. And then install the .apk files in the following order:

   - SAccessoryService_Emul.apk
   - SASystemProviders_ForEmul.apk
3. After installation, reboot and run the "**Emulator for Samsung Accessory**" application in the host device. The application will display a "**Disconnected**" message.

   [image]
4. To set up the connection between wearable emulator and host android device:

   - Connect the host device and PC using a USB connection.
   - Open the terminal or the command prompt in Windows.
   - Enter the command: adb -d forward tcp:8230 tcp:8230
   - Run the application "Emulator for Samsung Accessory" in the host device.
   - In the SDK, run the Emulator Manager and create a wearable emulator and run it.
   - If the 'Disconnected' message does not change, restart the emulator with the hardware key or the command **`shutdown –r now`**. *DO NOT use the command reboot.*

If you see a "Connected" message, that means you have successfully connected the wearable emulator with the host android device.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried everything as per your steps. But I'm not able to see connected. It's still displaying disconnected text.

Comment: I'm trying to connect samsung s4 and emulator 2.3. Are they compatible??

Comment: I'm able to connect 2.3.1 emulator only.  Emulator with 2.3 version is not getting connected.

Comment: @Priya I am having the same issue. I have Emulator with version 2.3.2. Does it matter?

Comment: @orhankutlu Sorry for the delay.. Yes.. It may be causing you the issue. because it didnt work for me with 2.3.. I'll try it today and update you.

Comment: @Priya It works fine now! It was not the emulator version. It was missing sdk for my problem

Comment: @orhankutlu  Great then!!

Comment: This doesn't work any more SAccessoryService_Emul.apk returns Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE], and Emul app is always "Disconnected" Any updates for this?